# Keyboard selection issue with contenteditable

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm seeing an issue where if you try to select `contenteditable` divs you can only select n-1 rows using keyboard navigation. This happens in safari and chrome so it doesn't seem like a browser bug. It's unclear why the red div to the right in the codepen below would prevent the last element from being selected.

To repro:
put the cursor in the first position (in front of the "one") then hold shift and navigate down to select the rows below - note it stops without selecting "three"

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div contenteditable="true">
      <div style="display: flex">
        <div>
          <div contenteditable="true">one</div>
          <div contenteditable="true">two</div>
          <div contenteditable="true">three</div>
        </div>
        <div contenteditable="false" style="width: 10px; background: red">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: That's not an error, you'd experience that in Word or Notepad, etc, too.

Comment: @LeeTaylor why isn't it an error? Is there any documentation that explains why you shouldn't be able to select the last element?

Comment: When you select with the keyboard and press down, you're selecting up to the next paragraph mark. As there isn't one, it "no longer works" as you've described.

Comment: I've tested Notepad and Visual Studio. They both do the same as your demo. Chrome's textarea, Word 2019 and WordPad allow selection of all three lines without the final line having a \r\n

Comment: But why would the outer contenteditable break it? if you remove the red div, or make it's height 0 or make it contenteditable=true it works.